# How to filter a Dataframe with information from other Dataframe using command filter

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a big Dataframe with a lot of information from different devices with their IDs. What I would like is to filter this Dataframe with the IDs that are in a second Dataframe. I know that I can easily do it with the command join, but I would like to try it with the command filter.

Also, I'm trying it because I've read that the command filter is more efficient than the join, could someone shed some light about it?

Thank you

I've tried this:

```
val DfFiltered = DF1.filter(col("Id").isin(DF2.rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect())
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Unsupported component type class java.lang.Object in arrays;
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 0d89d684-d794-407d-a03c-feb3ad6a78c2, runId = b7b774c0-ce83-461e-ac26-7535d6d2b0ac]
Current Committed Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[MeterEEM]]: {"MeterEEM":{"0":270902}}}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[MeterEEM]]: {"MeterEEM":{"0":271296}}}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
Project [value2#21.meterid AS meterid#23]
+- Project [jsontostructs(StructField(meterid,StringType,true), cast(value#8 as string), Some(Europe/Paris)) AS value2#21]
   +- StreamingExecutionRelation KafkaV2[Subscribe[MeterEEM]], [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unsupported component type class java.lang.Object in arrays;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.componentTypeToDataType(literals.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:164)
    at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.create(literals.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.typedLit(functions.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Column$$anonfun$isin$1.apply(Column.scala:796)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Column$$anonfun$isin$1.apply(Column.scala:796)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.isin(Column.scala:796)
    at StreamingProcedure.MetersEEM$.meterEemCalcs(MetersEEM.scala:28)
    at LaunchFunctions.LaunchMeterEEM$$anonfun$1.apply(LaunchMeterEEM.scala:23)
    at LaunchFunctions.LaunchMeterEEM$$anonfun$1.apply(LaunchMeterEEM.scala:15)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(ForeachBatchSink.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:534)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:532)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:531)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apacahe.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBtchExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 3):

I've made the assumption that the data in the `Id` column is of an `Integer` datatype.

```
val list = DF2.select("Id").as[Int] collect()

val DfFiltered = DF1.filter($"Id".isin(list: _*))

DfFiltered collect()
```

Comment: Just remember to be careful when using collect on big Dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

From High Performance Spark book, it's explained that:

> Joining data is an important part of many of our pipelines, and both Spark Core and SQL support the same fundamental types of joins. While joins are very common and powerful, they warrant special performance consideration as they may require large network transfers or even create datasets beyond our capability to handle.1 In core Spark it can be more important to think about the ordering of operations, since the DAG optimizer, unlike the SQL optimizer, isn’t able to re-order or push down filters.

So, choosing filter instead of join seems a good choice

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add (:_*)  to your code this would work perfectly fine.

```
scala> val DfFiltered = df.filter(col("a").isin(df2.rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect():_*)).show()
```